# Create customized model option in OpenAI Studio says no models available

Tags: azure, azure-openai

OpenAI access has been enabled on my subscription, however, when I try to use 'Create customized model' from the underlying base models to be able to fine-tune the data from a .jsonl file, it says there are no models available, check your access.
Is there a different access I need to request?

Screenshot

[image: 1]

I want to be able to successfully use the create a customized model wizard